# Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 81 of the JSON data

Tags: php, ajax

Cordial saludo a la comunidad, tengo un problema desde hace un mes y aún no he podido resolverlo, por favor necesito una ayuda.

Voy a hacer una búsqueda a través de un formulario a través de AJAX, he aquí el formulario:

```
<input type="search" id="buscar" class="form-control lead mr-1" placeholder="Digite el nombre del Cliente o Empresa a Actualizar" name="buscar" style="height: 50px" required><i class="btn submit-btn fas fa-search fa-2x input-group-text btnBuscar">
```

Ajax envía el dato a un controlador cada vez que se teclea un dato:

```
$('#buscar').keyup(function(e){
     let buscar = $('#buscar').val();
     $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'contenido.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {buscar},
        success: function(e){   
            var task =JSON.parse(e);
            console.log(task);
        }
    })      
})
```

El controlador lo recibe y envía el dato a la clase:

```
$buscar = $_POST['buscar'];
    if (!empty($buscar) AND isset($_POST['buscar'])){            
          $clienteName = filter_var(mb_strtolower($_POST['buscar']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
          $clienteByName = new Clientes();
          $resultClient = $clienteByName->showClientByName($clienteName);

          if ($resultClient != false) {             
            $nombres = $resultClient;
            echo $nombres;
          }else
          {
            $errores.='<li class="advertencias text-center bg-danger text-light lead">¡El Cliente con este nombre no existe!</li>';
          } 
    }
```

La clase recibe el dato del controlador y hace la búsqueda en la base de datos y retorna el array codificado con json_encode:

```
public function showClientByName(string $buscar)
{   
    $consulta = $this->bd->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$buscar."%' OR empresa LIKE '%".$buscar."%'");
    $resultado = $consulta->execute();      
    $datosCliente = $consulta->fetchAll();
    $datos = array();   
    if ($resultado != false) {
        foreach ($datosCliente as $key => $value) {             
            array_push($datos, array('nombre' => $value['nombre']));
        }                       
    }else{
        $datos = $resultado;
    }
    $datosStr = json_encode($datos);                        
    return $datosStr;
```

El controlador recibe este dato ya convertido en string y AJAX lo recibe y lo muestra en consola:

[{"nombre":"fabian andres vargas vasquez"},{"nombre":"fabian henao"},{"nombre":"fabian henao"}]

Un problema que noto es que no solo muestra el resultado sino que muestra también todo el contenido del HTML, no se como hacer para que muestre solo el string, ¿porque arrastra todo el código en la respuesta?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente el error se genera cuando convierto el string generado mediante la JSON.parse:

```
$('#buscar').keyup(function(e){
     let buscar = $('#buscar').val();
     $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'contenido.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {buscar},
        success: function(e){   
            var task =JSON.parse(e);
            console.log(task);
        }
    })      
})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si el error se genera porque después del string está intentando convertir el html generado seguido de la respuesta. Muchas gracias a quien pueda ayudarme con esto que de verdad me tiene con mucha sosobra.

Comment: El error que tienes ocurre cuando intentas aplicar JSON.parse a un dato que no contiene un JSON válido. Para evitarlo debes aplicar un control estricto en tu código PHP para que **no salga por pantalla nada que no sea un array convertido a JSON mediante `json_encode`**. En el flujo de tu código PHP no estás aplicando eso, veo por ejemplo una parte donde creas unos `li`... Todo lo que respondas debes meterlo en un array. Debes cuidar también la codificación, porque si no lo haces las palabras acentuadas pueden romper el código generando un JSON inválido. Es simple: controla tu código .

Comment: Hola gracias por tu comentario, pero la función json_encode se está aplicando en la función ShowClientByName arriba descrita, $datosStr = json_encode($datos);   que está generado este resultado [{"nombre":"fabian andres vargas vasquez"},{"nombre":"fabian henao"},{"nombre":"fabian henao"}] el cual está bien porque es un string de tipo json, el problema ocurre es cuando se aplica json.parse pero noto que en la respuesta se trae continuamente todo el código html del script, tal vez está intentando convertir el string devuelto mas todo ese código que se trae. ¿como mostrar solo el array?

Comment: Lo puse en negritas en mi comentario anterior y lo repito de nuevo. Cuando pides un JSON desde Ajax, el archivo que procesa la petición **no debe permitir que salga por pantalla ninguna otra cosa que un JSON válido**. Si sale código HTML u otro es porque no estás observando ese criterio. Debes revisar tu archivo `contenido.php`  y controlar las salidas. Eso significa que en ese archivo no puedes tener contenido HTML o `echo` o `print` o cualquier otra cosa que no sea el JSON.